# How to scan specific Bluetooth device and get information from it in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, rssi

I try to build a project that can get Bluetooth rssi from specific devices. However, I'm stuck on that. Is there any way to filter and specify the scanning results and then continuously get information from the chosen Bluetooth devices? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes
You can filter using device MAC address in android

```
//lets say i have a device i got by searching BT devices

  BluetoothDevice device;
  String mac = "00:11:22:AA:BB:CC"
  if(mac.equals(device.getAddress)){

       // my device found 
     }
```

**public String getAddress ()**

Added in API level 5

Returns the hardware address of this BluetoothDevice.

Bluetooth hardware address as string

for more see Android [BluetoothDevice doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getAddress%28%29)

Comment: Can u provide some sample code so that I can refer to? And what about tge continuous scanning? Thx

Comment: I'd be interested in this too.